# What to change Caucasian to on forms?

Tags: word-choice, forms-of-address

I recently was called for jury duty in Wisconsin and was surprised to see Caucasian as a race choice. I called the clerk and she said most people check other and write white. What other designation should this be on the form? European American?

Comment: Are you able to change/add the race options on the forms?

Comment: 'American' isn't a race, but a nationality. If you weren't American you would not be called for jury duty in an American court. I guess people don't check 'Caucasian' because they don't know what it means.

Comment: Leave it blank. Or lie. _Race_ does not describe anything real, so it's irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

In the early days of the United States, there was a difference between "caucasian" and "white." Citizenship was extended to "free white persons," but Native American Indians were not considered "white." This was later resolved through legislation.

Today, there's not really a difference between the two categories. The United States Census uses the term "white," so that would presumably be a more common or accepted term.

While much less common, "European" is sometimes used to describe race. For example, "he is of European descent" (as opposed to Asian descent or Latin descent) would imply that he is white when used in the context of race.

Comment: I thought Latin descent implied at least partial descent from Spanish or Portuguese ancestors, Spain and Portugal are definitely European countries. Caucasian, to me, means descent from northern European or west Asian Russian ancestors.